# C# DateTime to "YYYYMMDDHHMMSS" format

Tags: c#, datetime, date-format

I want to convert a C# DateTime to "YYYYMMDDHHMMSS" format. But I don't find a built in method to get this format? Any comments?

Answer (score 1285, accepted):

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss"); // case sensitive
```

Comment: is it just me who thinks it's nuts to have big M's for months then big H's for hours?

Comment: m = minutes / M = months, h = 12 hour, H = 24 hour.  I suspect someone started with time and said hms = hours mins seconds, then H became 24 hour and then they got to date and ran out of unique letters so went with case.  Just one of those things.

Comment: How would you parse that back in using `DateTime.Parse()`?

Comment: @BigMoney you would use DateTime.ParseExact:  var now = DateTime.ParseExact(stringVersion, "YYYYMMDDHHMMSS", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

Comment: @Nick: May be MS wanted to give it a camel sense, but SS needed to be capital as well. Sorry I meant CamelCase

Comment: @BigMoney When parsing, the `format` is also case sensitive, i.e. `DateTime.ParseExact(stringValue, "yyyyMMddHHmmss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);`

Comment: Use f for fractions of a second. f = tenths of a second, ff = hundredth of a second and so on.

Comment: convert ***"yyyyMMddHHmmss" to long*** ?

Comment: @NigelTouch Can we pass any type of date format in to stringValue in above code?

Answer (score 722):

[This site has great examples](http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-datetime/) check it out

```
// create date time 2008-03-09 16:05:07.123
DateTime dt = new DateTime(2008, 3, 9, 16, 5, 7, 123);

String.Format("{0:y yy yyy yyyy}",      dt);  // "8 08 008 2008"   year
String.Format("{0:M MM MMM MMMM}",      dt);  // "3 03 Mar March"  month
String.Format("{0:d dd ddd dddd}",      dt);  // "9 09 Sun Sunday" day
String.Format("{0:h hh H HH}",          dt);  // "4 04 16 16"      hour 12/24
String.Format("{0:m mm}",               dt);  // "5 05"            minute
String.Format("{0:s ss}",               dt);  // "7 07"            second
String.Format("{0:f ff fff ffff}",      dt);  // "1 12 123 1230"   sec.fraction
String.Format("{0:F FF FFF FFFF}",      dt);  // "1 12 123 123"    without zeroes
String.Format("{0:t tt}",               dt);  // "P PM"            A.M. or P.M.
String.Format("{0:z zz zzz}",           dt);  // "-6 -06 -06:00"   time zone

// month/day numbers without/with leading zeroes
String.Format("{0:M/d/yyyy}",           dt);  // "3/9/2008"
String.Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}",         dt);  // "03/09/2008"

// day/month names
String.Format("{0:ddd, MMM d, yyyy}",   dt);  // "Sun, Mar 9, 2008"
String.Format("{0:dddd, MMMM d, yyyy}", dt);  // "Sunday, March 9, 2008"

// two/four digit year
String.Format("{0:MM/dd/yy}",           dt);  // "03/09/08"
String.Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}",         dt);  // "03/09/2008"
```

**Standard DateTime Formatting**

```
String.Format("{0:t}", dt);  // "4:05 PM"                           ShortTime
String.Format("{0:d}", dt);  // "3/9/2008"                          ShortDate
String.Format("{0:T}", dt);  // "4:05:07 PM"                        LongTime
String.Format("{0:D}", dt);  // "Sunday, March 09, 2008"            LongDate
String.Format("{0:f}", dt);  // "Sunday, March 09, 2008 4:05 PM"    LongDate+ShortTime
String.Format("{0:F}", dt);  // "Sunday, March 09, 2008 4:05:07 PM" FullDateTime
String.Format("{0:g}", dt);  // "3/9/2008 4:05 PM"                  ShortDate+ShortTime
String.Format("{0:G}", dt);  // "3/9/2008 4:05:07 PM"               ShortDate+LongTime
String.Format("{0:m}", dt);  // "March 09"                          MonthDay
String.Format("{0:y}", dt);  // "March, 2008"                       YearMonth
String.Format("{0:r}", dt);  // "Sun, 09 Mar 2008 16:05:07 GMT"     RFC1123
String.Format("{0:s}", dt);  // "2008-03-09T16:05:07"               SortableDateTime
String.Format("{0:u}", dt);  // "2008-03-09 16:05:07Z"              UniversalSortableDateTime

/*
Specifier   DateTimeFormatInfo property     Pattern value (for en-US culture)
    t           ShortTimePattern                    h:mm tt
    d           ShortDatePattern                    M/d/yyyy
    T           LongTimePattern                     h:mm:ss tt
    D           LongDatePattern                     dddd, MMMM dd, yyyy
    f           (combination of D and t)            dddd, MMMM dd, yyyy h:mm tt
    F           FullDateTimePattern                 dddd, MMMM dd, yyyy h:mm:ss tt
    g           (combination of d and t)            M/d/yyyy h:mm tt
    G           (combination of d and T)            M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss tt
    m, M        MonthDayPattern                     MMMM dd
    y, Y        YearMonthPattern                    MMMM, yyyy
    r, R        RFC1123Pattern                      ddd, dd MMM yyyy HH':'mm':'ss 'GMT' (*)
    s           SortableDateTi­mePattern             yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss (*)
    u           UniversalSorta­bleDateTimePat­tern    yyyy'-'MM'-'dd HH':'mm':'ss'Z' (*)
                                                    (*) = culture independent   
*/
```

**Update**
using c# 6 string interpolation format

```
// create date time 2008-03-09 16:05:07.123
DateTime dt = new DateTime(2008, 3, 9, 16, 5, 7, 123);

$"{dt:y yy yyy yyyy}";  // "8 08 008 2008"   year
$"{dt:M MM MMM MMMM}";  // "3 03 Mar March"  month
$"{dt:d dd ddd dddd}";  // "9 09 Sun Sunday" day
$"{dt:h hh H HH}";      // "4 04 16 16"      hour 12/24
$"{dt:m mm}";           // "5 05"            minute
$"{dt:s ss}";           // "7 07"            second
$"{dt:f ff fff ffff}";  // "1 12 123 1230"   sec.fraction
$"{dt:F FF FFF FFFF}";  // "1 12 123 123"    without zeroes
$"{dt:t tt}";           // "P PM"            A.M. or P.M.
$"{dt:z zz zzz}";       // "-6 -06 -06:00"   time zone

// month/day numbers without/with leading zeroes
$"{dt:M/d/yyyy}";    // "3/9/2008"
$"{dt:MM/dd/yyyy}";  // "03/09/2008"

// day/month names
$"{dt:ddd, MMM d, yyyy}";    // "Sun, Mar 9, 2008"
$"{dt:dddd, MMMM d, yyyy}";  // "Sunday, March 9, 2008"

// two/four digit year
$"{dt:MM/dd/yy}";    // "03/09/08"
$"{dt:MM/dd/yyyy}";  // "03/09/2008"
```

Comment: I would like this format:  `yyyyMMddHHmm[+-]ZZzz` where ***The [+-]ZZzz part is the timezone (the number of hours to be added or substracted from GMT date)***

Comment: `zzz` is ***-06:00*** , I would like `-0600`

Comment: @Kiquenet have you tried `.Replace(":", "")`  `$"{dt:yyyyMMddHHmmzzz}".Replace(":", "")` as a work around

Comment: An alternative is `dt.ToString("...");`, where replace `"..."` with a format above, eg. `"yyyy-MM-dd"`.

Answer (score 266):

You've practically written the format yourself.

`yourdate.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss")`

- MM = two digit month
- mm = two digit minutes
- HH = two digit hour, 24 hour clock
- hh = two digit hour, 12 hour clock

Everything else should be self-explanatory.

Comment: "fff" will give the milliseconds so you can use "yyyyMMddHHmmssfff" to give a string down to the milliseconds.

Comment: Which is part for  the timezone (the number of hours to be added or substracted from GMT date) ?

Answer (score 147):

You've just got to be careful between months (MM) and minutes (mm):

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Now; // Or whatever
string s = dt.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
```

(Also note that HH is 24 hour clock, whereas hh would be 12 hour clock, usually in conjunction with t or tt for the am/pm designator.)

If you want to do this as part of a composite format string, you'd use:

```
string s = string.Format("The date/time is: {0:yyyyMMddHHmmss}", dt);
```

For further information, see the [MSDN page on custom date and time formats](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx).

Comment: is it possible to: `now.ToString("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss")`? I mean is possible to concatenate with other characters, correct?

Comment: @DanielV: Yes, but I would quote the literal characters (with apostrophes).

Answer (score 41):

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") 05/29/2015
DateTime.Now.ToString("dddd, dd MMMM yyyy") Friday, 29 May 2015
DateTime.Now.ToString("dddd, dd MMMM yyyy") Friday, 29 May 2015 05:50
DateTime.Now.ToString("dddd, dd MMMM yyyy") Friday, 29 May 2015 05:50 AM
DateTime.Now.ToString("dddd, dd MMMM yyyy") Friday, 29 May 2015 5:50
DateTime.Now.ToString("dddd, dd MMMM yyyy") Friday, 29 May 2015 5:50 AM
DateTime.Now.ToString("dddd, dd MMMM yyyy HH:mm:ss")    Friday, 29 May 2015 05:50:06
DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm")   05/29/2015 05:50
DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt")    05/29/2015 05:50 AM
DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy H:mm")    05/29/2015 5:50
DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy h:mm tt") 05/29/2015 5:50 AM
DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss")    05/29/2015 05:50:06
DateTime.Now.ToString("MMMM dd")    May 29
DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy’-‘MM’-‘dd’T’HH’:’mm’:’ss.fffffffK") 2015-05-16T05:50:06.7199222-04:00
DateTime.Now.ToString("ddd, dd MMM yyy HH’:’mm’:’ss ‘GMT’") Fri, 16 May 2015 05:50:06 GMT
DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy’-‘MM’-‘dd’T’HH’:’mm’:’ss")  2015-05-16T05:50:06
DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm")  05:50
DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm tt")   05:50 AM
DateTime.Now.ToString("H:mm")   5:50
DateTime.Now.ToString("h:mm tt")    5:50 AM
DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss")   05:50:06
DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy MMMM")  2015 May
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the single quotes in the format string?

Comment: @M.M It escapes the text in between them, so it isn't transformed during formatting.
Without them `:` can be changed to `.` for some cultures. With escaping, you are ensuring, that the `':'` will remain `:` in all cultures.

Answer (score 30):

You can use a custom format string:

```
DateTime d = DateTime.Now;
string dateString = d.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
```

Substitute "hh" for "HH" if you do not want 24-hour clock time.

Answer (score 26):

If you use ReSharper, get help with ':' (see image)

[image: Intellisense]

Comment: You get the same with 2013 (and probably before) with ReSharper.

Answer (score 22):

In `.Net Standard 2` you can format `DateTime` like belows:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
CultureInfo iv = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;

// Default formats
// D - long date           Tuesday, 24 April 2018
// d - short date          04/24/2018
// F - full date long      Tuesday, 24 April 2018 06:30:00
// f - full date short     Tuesday, 24 April 2018 06:30
// G - general long        04/24/2018 06:30:00
// g - general short       04/24/2018 06:30
// U - universal full      Tuesday, 24 April 2018 06:30:00
// u - universal sortable  2018-04-24 06:30:00
// s - sortable            2018-04-24T06:30:00
// T - long time           06:30:00
// t - short time          06:30
// O - ISO 8601            2018-04-24T06:30:00.0000000
// R - RFC 1123            Tue, 24 Apr 2018 06:30:00 GMT           
// M - month               April 24
// Y - year month          2018 April
Console.WriteLine(dt.ToString("D", iv));

// Custom formats
// M/d/yy                  4/8/18
// MM/dd/yyyy              04/08/2018
// yy-MM-dd                08-04-18
// yy-MMM-dd ddd           08-Apr-18 Sun
// yyyy-M-d dddd           2018-4-8 Sunday
// yyyy MMMM dd            2018 April 08      
// h:mm:ss tt zzz          4:03:05 PM -03
// HH:m:s tt zzz           16:03:05 -03:00
// hh:mm:ss t z            04:03:05 P -03
// HH:mm:ss tt zz          16:03:05 PM -03      
Console.WriteLine(dt.ToString("M/d/yy", iv));
```

Answer (score 20):

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
```

if you just want it displayed as a string

Answer (score 13):

```
string date = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MMM-yy");  //05-Aug-13
```

Answer (score 10):

I am surprised no one has a link for this . 
any format can be created using the guidelines here:

[Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

For your specific example (As others have indicated) use something like

```
my_format="yyyyMMddHHmmss";
DateTime.Now.ToString(my_format);
```

Where my_format can be any string combination of y,M,H,m,s,f,F and more!
Check out the link.

Comment: Jon Skeet included that link in his answer (http://stackoverflow.com/a/3025377/12484).

Answer (score 10):

Get the date as a `DateTime` object instead of a String. Then you can format it as you want.

- MM/dd/yyyy    08/22/2006
- dddd, dd MMMM yyyy    Tuesday, 22 August 2006
- dddd, dd MMMM yyyy HH:mm  Tuesday, 22 August 2006 06:30
- dddd, dd MMMM yyyy hh:mm tt   Tuesday, 22 August 2006 06:30 AM
- dddd, dd MMMM yyyy H:mm   Tuesday, 22 August 2006 6:30
- dddd, dd MMMM yyyy h:mm tt    Tuesday, 22 August 2006 6:30 AM
- dddd, dd MMMM yyyy HH:mm:ss   Tuesday, 22 August 2006 06:30:07
- MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm  08/22/2006 06:30
- MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt   08/22/2006 06:30 AM
- MM/dd/yyyy H:mm   08/22/2006 6:30
- MM/dd/yyyy h:mm tt    08/22/2006 6:30 AM
- MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss   08/22/2006 06:30:07

[Click here for more patterns](https://blog.nicholasrogoff.com/2012/05/05/c-datetime-tostring-formats-quick-reference/)

Answer (score 6):

using C# 6.0

```
$"Date-{DateTime.Now:yyyyMMddHHmmss}"
```

Answer (score 5):

Specify formatted DateTime as Utc:

Step 1 - Initial date

```
var initialDtm = DateTime.Now;
```

Step 2 - Format date as willing ("yyyyMMddHHmmss")

```
var formattedDtm = DateTime.ParseExact(initialDtm.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss"), "yyyyMMddHHmmss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Step 3 - Specify kind of date (Utc)

```
var specifiedDtm = DateTime.SpecifyKind(formattedDtm, DateTimeKind.Utc);
```

Answer (score 3):

An easy Method, Full control over 'from type' and 'to type', and only need to remember this code for future castings

```
DateTime.ParseExact(InputDate, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString("yyyy/MM/dd"));
```

Answer (score 3):

It is not a big deal. you can simply put like this

```
WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd-HH:mm:ss")}");
```

Excuse here for I used $ which is for string Interpolation .

Comment: I recently did just that: And for some reason my tests failed on one build agent running Danish locale. While `-` is a literal `:` is in fact a symbol resolved depending on the current locale. In Danish that would be `.` causing a rather unexpected result `2019-04-15-12.39.00` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings?redirectedfrom=MSDN#timeSeparator

Answer (score 1):

Chances are slim that any of the above answers wouldn't has solved your problem. Nonetheless, I'm sharing my method which always works for me for different format of datetimes.

```
//Definition   
     public static DateTime ConvertPlainStringToDatetime(string Date, string inputFormat, string  outputFormat)
            {
                DateTime date;
                CultureInfo enUS = new CultureInfo("en-US");
                DateTime.TryParseExact(Date, inputFormat, enUS,
                                    DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal, out date);

                string formatedDateTime = date.ToString(outputFormat);
                return Convert.ToDateTime(formatedDateTime);   
            }
//Calling

    string oFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";
    DateTime requiredDT = ConvertPlainStringToDatetime("20190205","yyyyMMddHHmmss", oFormat  );
    DateTime requiredDT = ConvertPlainStringToDatetime("20190508-12:46:42","yyyyMMdd-HH:mm:ss", oFormat);
```

Answer (score -2):

After spent a lot of hours on Google search, I found the below solution as when I locally give date time, no exception while from other server, there was Error......... Date is not in proper format.. Before saving/ searching Text box date time in C#, just checking either the outer Serer Culture is same like database server culture.. Ex both should be "en-US" or must be both "en-GB" asp below snap shot.

[image]

Even with different date format like (dd/mm/yyyy) or (yyyy/mm/dd), it will save or search accurately.

Comment: Have to capitalize those m's - M is Month, m is minute. These would give you for example 2017/51/10

Comment: Its just showing the date format might be day/month/year or year/month/day.......... it will search despite of culture difference... dont confuse with time................ this format can be set on dateTimePicker calander........