# Conversion from String to DateTime in C#

Tags: c#, sql, datetime

I want to convert a String to Datetime. I'm getting an error `This is not a valid datetime`.

The string I want to convert and code are as follows.

```
string date1 = "9/13/2012 5:26:06 PM";
TimePart = DateTime.ParseExact(date1, "M/d/yyyy HH:mm:ss tt", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: You might find that useful: [DateTime.ToString() patterns](http://www.geekzilla.co.uk/View00FF7904-B510-468C-A2C8-F859AA20581F.htm)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3025916/1731716 this link might help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the lowercase `h`:

```
DateTime TimePart = DateTime.ParseExact(
                                date1,
                                "M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss tt",
                                CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

Console.WriteLine(TimePart); // 09/13/2012 17:26:06
```

Uppercase "H" is 24-hour time, lowercase "h" is 12-hour time with AM/PM.

Answer (score 6):

I think it should be `M/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss tt` in your format parameter.

Comment: No. Even that is not working. Error is String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Comment: @ShamiC i just updated the answer, since you have added `tt`, it is not in `24-hr` format anymore. so change `HH` into `hh`

Comment: @JohnWoo - And since `hh` expects a leading `0` for a single digit hour, you need to remove the extra `h`.

Comment: This is inaccurate without @Oded's correction.  Why is it getting so many upvotes? (I downvoted)

Comment: @TimS. you're right. I updated it after Oded's correction. Am I not allow to update the answer? If I have the ability to change the upvotes of my answer. I will give it all to you. :)

Comment: I suspect you need to replace `dd` with `d` too, since the OP probably wants to be able to parse single digit days.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like your format is really `M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss tt`.  The difference is `h` (12-hour, with only as many digits as needed) instead of `HH` (24-hour, with leading 0 to pad to 2 digits).

If the input format can vary at all, you should use [`DateTime.Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6fw7727c.aspx) instead so that you don't have to tell it the exact format.  `ParseExact` is faster, and requires that it matches the specified format, which may be preferable in your cast.

Answer (score 2):

You should be using a lower case `h` for a 12 hour clock (since you have an `AM/PM` designator).

Additionally, you should only use one `h`, as you don't have a leading `0` to the hours, and `hh` expects it.

A format string that works:

```
"M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss tt"
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the `HH` isn't matching the "5". Try `h`.

Comment: This really should be a comment