# How to Convert a Date String with Format "dd/MM/yyyy" to OS Current Culture Date Format

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2008, datetime

A string has the value in "**dd/MM/yyyy**" format like "**04/10/2012**". This should be converted to a Date w.r.t **Current Culture** of **OS**.

I have tried below string with **Korean as Current Culture** of OS in which date format is **yyyy-MM-dd**, my code is not getting correct Month value, it interchange the month value with day:

Input: "**04/10/2012**"
Output: **2012-04-10**

Code:

```
DateTime DT;
string dt = "04/10/2012";

DateTimeFormatInfo DateInfo = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat;
DT = Convert.ToDateTime(String.Format ("{0:"+DateInfo .ShortDatePattern +"}", dt.Trim ()), CultureInfo .CurrentCulture);
MessageBox.Show("Date: " + DT.ToShortDateString());
```

How I can fix that ?

Comment: Refer to [.Net Standard 2 samples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3025361/c-sharp-datetime-to-yyyymmddhhmmss-format/50508087#50508087)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks to me like you need to parse it with a fixed format, I think you are currently parsing it with a format other than "dd/MM/yyyy" and because the date is ambiguous (as in, month and day can be interchanged without causing invalid dates) the format is simply switching the month and day value. When you then go to output it, it looks reversed.

Use `DateTime.ParseExact` to force the parsing format and then use the built-in current culture sensitive string output methods on `DateTime` to get a formatted string:

```
var date = DateTime.ParseExact("04/10/2012", "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

MessageBox.Show("Date: " + date.ToShortDateString()); // Assumes current culture is controlling format
```

Answer (score 2):

Since your input string is in a fixed format, you should parse it in that format:

```
DateTime.ParseExact(dt, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you string has the format `dd/MM/yyyy` then you *have* to use [`DateTime.ParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx) with the specified format:

```
DateTime.ParseExact(dt, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Anything else will try an interpret the string according to the current culture's rules - which, as you have found, will fail.

Answer (score 0):

why not use `ToShortDateTimeString()`