# Change datetime format in C#

Tags: c#, datetime

Hey I'm using a Randomdate function in C# (it was written by another person here on StackOverflow - thank you :) )
Anyway it returns a random date between two dates, but in this format

the code:

```
public static DateTime RandomDay()
{
    DateTime start = new DateTime(2006, 1, 1);
    DateTime end = new DateTime(2013, 12, 31);

    Random gen = new Random();

    int range = (end - start).Days;
    return start.AddDays(gen.Next(range));
}
```

However, this returns a date in a format like 2008-10-25,
however, i want the dates to represented like this:

```
25.10.2008:00:00.000
```

Is this possible?
Thanks

Comment: You can specify locales to which dates are formatted.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the given method. Simply use one of the ToString overloads to format the `DateTime`.

Comment: Duplicate question see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3025361/c-sharp-datetime-to-yyyymmddhhmmss-format

Comment: I find your lack of research disturbing. ([first result on Google](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) for "format date C#")

Comment: -1, I did a [Google search](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&ie=UTF-8#hl=en&sclient=psy-ab&q=Change%20datetime%20format%20in%20C%23&oq=&gs_l=&pbx=1&fp=a50db3676f095c3b&ion=1&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.46751780,d.bGE&biw=1920&bih=1139) on your question title, [this is what I got as the first result](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)

Answer (score 5):

Call `ToString()` on the date and pass your desired format.

```
var formatted = date.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy:HH:mm.fff");
```

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at the MSDN documentation page:

[Custom date and time format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)

```
string formattedDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy:HH:mm:ss:fff");
```

Comment: Bidou, add some details with your answer, link only answers are discouraged.

Answer (score 0):

could you try this:

```
string urdate = RandomDay().ToString("dd.MM.yyyy:HH:mm.fff");
```

Answer (score 0):

DateTimes don't have a format. Instead, they store the date and time as the number of 100 nanosecond ticks since 12:00 midnight, January 1, 0001 A.D. inside a field of type `long`.

When you convert them to a string, then that string *does* have a format.

So what you need to do is to specify the format that you want as a parameter to a call to `DateTime.ToString()`.

In your case, the correct format is specified by `"dd.MM.yyyy:HH:mm.fff"`, so you can achieve what you want by doing:

```
DateTime myDate = RandomDay();
string myFormattedDateString = myDate.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy:HH:mm.fff");
```

[See here for information about DateTime.ToString()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw.aspx)

[See here for information about the custom DateTime formatting strings such as the ones used in this answer.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
string urdate = RandomDay().Now.ToShortDateString();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can supply a format string, such as:

```
RandomDay().ToString("dd.MM.yyyy:hh.mm.sss")
```

See [Custom Date Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)