# Date/time in input field

Tags: c#, sql

I want to fill the input field with the data in my database but i am getting the following error:

> Can't convert date time object to string

Here is the code:

```
ll.LeerlingGeboortedatum = (string)(DT.Rows[0]["LeerlingGeboortedatum"]);
txtLeerlingGeboortedatum.Text = ll.LeerlingGeboortedatum;
```

Thanks for your time!

Comment: use to string instead of casting it

Comment: don't cast call ToString()

Comment: Where's the SQL?

Answer (score 1):

```
txtLeerlingGeboortedatum.Text = DT.Rows[0]["LeerlingGeboortedatum"].ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this please:

```
ll.LeerlingGeboortedatum = DT.Rows[0]["LeerlingGeboortedatum"].ToString();
txtLeerlingGeboortedatum.Text = ll.LeerlingGeboortedatum;
```

Answer (score 0):

As Mentioned in the comment, use the ToString() Method instead of casting it.
Have a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18874187/4992212) for more information. Using the paramters in the ToString method you can also specify how the dateString should look like, and which information it holds.

[Here](http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-datetime/) are some examples how these paramters work.

```
ll.LeerlingGeboortedatum = DT.Rows[0]["LeerlingGeboortedatum"].ToString();
txtLeerlingGeboortedatum.Text = ll.LeerlingGeboortedatum;
```

> Quote token from http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-datetime/.
>   quotet it in case the site gets down in the future.
>
> ```
> // create date time 2008-03-09 16:05:07.123
> DateTime dt = new DateTime(2008, 3, 9, 16, 5, 7, 123);
>
> String.Format("{0:y yy yyy yyyy}", dt);  // "8 08 008 2008"   year
> String.Format("{0:M MM MMM MMMM}", dt);  // "3 03 Mar March"  month
> String.Format("{0:d dd ddd dddd}", dt);  // "9 09 Sun Sunday" day
> String.Format("{0:h hh H HH}",     dt);  // "4 04 16 16"      hour 12/24
> String.Format("{0:m mm}",          dt);  // "5 05"            minute
> String.Format("{0:s ss}",          dt);  // "7 07"            second
> String.Format("{0:f ff fff ffff}", dt);  // "1 12 123 1230"   sec.fraction
> String.Format("{0:F FF FFF FFFF}", dt);  // "1 12 123 123"    without zeroes
> String.Format("{0:t tt}",          dt);  // "P PM"            A.M. or P.M.
> String.Format("{0:z zz zzz}",      dt);  // "-6 -06 -06:00"   time zone
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead of your code :

```
ll.LeerlingGeboortedatum = DT.Rows[0]["LeerlingGeboortedatum"];
txtLeerlingGeboortedatum.Text = ll.LeerlingGeboortedatum.ToString();
```