# Add colon to 24 hour time in C#?

Tags: c#

I have time stored in Db as 800,1600 format in separate column. I want to  add colon in time before giving it to UI. Currently I am calculating the size and zero if size is three and  using insert to add colon after 2 characters.

```
String.Insert(2,':');
```

Is there any better way to do the same?

Comment: Is your DB field a string, or a time?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3025361/c-sharp-datetime-to-yyyymmddhhmmss-format helpful link for you

Comment: Can you paste your sophisticated code (full one) to put colon into time?

Comment: @shannon it's string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below code

```
string time = "800";
string s1= DateTime.ParseExact(time.PadLeft(4, '0') , "HHmm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString("HH:mm");
```

Comment: Since OP has no preceding zero already it should be `Hmm`

Comment: `Hmm` isn't working. zero needs to be appended

Comment: `time.PadLeft(4, '0')` is nicer than that ternary :)

Comment: @poke Thanks. Yeah i was looking for something similar