# Convert DateTime in another format

Tags: c#, datetime

I have an object, one of its propperty is DateTime DateofBirth. i get this object and want to change

> {8/16/1978 12:00:00 AM}

to

> {16/8/1978 12:00:00 AM}

.

```
DateTime? tmp = externalConsumerProfile.DateOfBirth;
string s=DateTime.ParseExact(tmp.ToString(), "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt") ;
```

But i have an error when try to convert

> An exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>   but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

When i try `tmp.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt")` z have an error

> No overloads for method ToString

Comment: You have a `DateTime` object, and then try to parse it as a `DateTime` object

Comment: `Parse` converts a `string` to a `DateTime`.  `tmp` IS already a `DateTime`, you don't need to make it one. Just format it.  `var s = tmp.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt");`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# DateTime to "YYYYMMDDHHMMSS" format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3025361/c-sharp-datetime-to-yyyymmddhhmmss-format)

Comment: `tmp.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt");`

Comment: No overloads for method ToString

Comment: `DateTime` doesn't _have_ a format.  You specify the format when _displaying_ it, which is where you need to make the change.

Comment: You are right..it is a nullable DateTime, you need to use `tmp.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt");`

Comment: How i can store changed `externalConsumerProfile.DateOfBirth = DateTime.ParseExact(dateOfBirths, "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);`  I see that `externalConsumerProfile.DateOfBirth` still the same

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need to do is format your DateTime value.  You don't need to parse it.

```
DateTime? tmp = externalConsumerProfile.DateOfBirth;
string s=tmp.HasValue() ? tmp.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt") : string.Empty;
```

Comment: No overloads for method ToString

Comment: @Евгений fixed `ToString`. Thx!

Comment: How i can store changed `externalConsumerProfile.DateOfBirth = DateTime.ParseExact(s, "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);`  I see that `externalConsumerProfile.DateOfBirth` still the same

Comment: `DateTime` variables don't have an intrinsic format.  Only when you need to output their value that a format is required, so you never store in a specific date/time format.