# asp.net/C#: Convert to 24 hour in linq query

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

i have linq query i want to convert the entrance **date** in the select new linq query, this is the query:

```
   var query = (from con in db.Containers
                         join v in db.Vehicles on con.cont_vehicleid equals v.vehl_VehicleID
                         join cust in db.Custom_Captions on v.vehl_state equals cust.Capt_Code
                         where cust.Capt_Family == "vehl_state" && v.vehl_state!= "Incoming" && v.vehl_Deleted == null && con.cont_Deleted == null && v.vehl_ClearanceCompany == p.pusr_CompanyId
                         select new
                         {
                             cont_name = con.cont_Name,
                             vehl_Name = v.vehl_Name,
                             VehicleState = cust.Capt_AR,
                             vehl_drivername = v.vehl_drivername,
                             vehl_entrancedate = v.vehl_entrancedate,
                             vehl_customsdec = v.vehl_customsdec,
                             cont_rampid = v.vehl_rampid
                         }
                   );
```

how to convert the:

```
vehl_entrancedate = v.vehl_entrancedate,
```

as 24 hour??

the output form the previous code:

[image]

**But**,i want to display with 24 hour and without AM/PM
like this :9/26/2016 11:55:58

or if the the time is 4:00 PM it will display 16:00

Note that the entrancedate field is type of datetime in database.

Comment: what?  how is a `date` different from a `24 hour date`?  Date implies only the date portion, not the time.  If you're actually working with a `datetime`, then there is no "format" a datetime is a datetime is a datetime.  If you need to change its format for display, use an appropriate date format with `ToString`

Comment: Do you need a date in 24 hours string format? Use ToString("HH:MM:ss")

Comment: @Kritner I have update the question

Comment: @celerno could you give me an explanation because it gives me an overloaded error

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# DateTime to "YYYYMMDDHHMMSS" format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3025361/c-sharp-datetime-to-yyyymmddhhmmss-format)

Comment: You haven't given enough information Fares.  For example, what `type` is `vehl_entrancedate`?  Is it a `DateTime`?  `DateTime`s have no "format" they are already `DateTimes`, and have all of the information in them to represent that date in any format you'd like.  It is unclear what problem you're actually having.  Is it a display/ui issue?  You say you want to display it in a specific way, it's just `vehl_entrancedate.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");` assuming that `vehl_entrancedate` is already a `datetime`

Comment: @Kritner i update the question.

Comment: @Kritner when i vehl_entrancedate.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss"); it givevs me an error no overload for method 'ToString' takes 1 argument

Comment: @Nkosi in database it's datetime

Comment: @FaresAyyad is your model class a `DateTime` or is it a `DateTime?`?  Is your DB columns a nullable `DateTime`?

Comment: Try this  vehl_entrancedate = v.vehl_entrancedate.Value.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i got it like that :

```
<td style="width:125px;"><%#Eval("vehl_entrancedate") == null ? "" : ((DateTime)Eval("vehl_entrancedate")).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm") %></td>
```