# How to change Date to RIGHT Format in JSON response in c#

Tags: c#, json, ajax, date

I am just new to AJAX and JSON, JSON response etc many things are interleaved I don't know how these are working.

I just want to change the format of DATE in JSON response, I am getting response like this:

```
/Date(-62135596800000)/
```

I just want to change it into the HUMAN readable DATE format.
HERE is the way how I am getting the values from database through DataTable using the columns from database and putting values into the view in c#.

```html
 $('#myDbTable')
            .DataTable({
                ajax: {
                    url: "@Url.Action("GetVouchers", "Vouchers")",
                type: "GET",
                dataType: "json",
                dataSrc: 'DataSet',

            },
                "columns": [
                    { "data": "FinancialYearName" },
                    { "data": "CompanyName" },
                    { "data": "BusinessUnitName" },
                    { "data": "VoucherTypeName" },
                    { "data": "Prefix" },
                    { "data": "Code" },
                    { "data": "VoucherDate" },
                    { "data": "Status" }
                    
                ],
                "aoColumnDefs": [
                    {
                        "aTargets": [DataColumnsCount],
                        "mData": null,
                        "bSortable": false,
                        "mRender": function(data, type, fullRow) {
                            //                       console.log(fullRow);
                            
                            return '<a class="btn btn-info btn-sm" href=#/' + fullRow["Id"] + '>' + 'Edit' + '</a>';
                        }

                    }
                ]

            });
```

{ "data": "VoucherDate" } is the column which is showing the Date into the dataTable using the database column.

[This is the image of OUTPUT for Date](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zuXE8.jpg)

I want to show it like 24 January, 2017.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I format a Microsoft JSON date?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/206384/how-do-i-format-a-microsoft-json-date)

Answer (score 0):

You can define a custom `render` function for your column where you could format the data coming from your server to a desired output:

```
{ 
    data: 'VoucherDate', 
    render: function (data, type, row) {
        var date = new Date(parseInt(data.replace("/Date(", "").replace(")/",""), 10));
        return date;
    }
}
```

Of course a much better solution would be to modify your server side serializer so that instead of splitting this format, it uses some more standard date format like ISO 8601 for example.

It seems that you are using ASP.NET MVC, so I would recommend you [`switching to the`Json.NET`serializer`](http://james.newtonking.com/archive/2008/10/16/asp-net-mvc-and-json-net) instead of relying on the `JavaScriptSerializer` class.

Comment: i have edited my question now full code block is given into the snippet u please take a look and reply me .

Comment: I have already shown in my answer how you can use the `render` function when defining the `VoucherDate` column. There's not much I can add to it.

Comment: i dont know how to use this in my code please do this for me :/ i don't know where to put render there is already mRender in the snippet

Comment: You put it inside your `columns` definition. Currently you have this in your code: `{ "data": "VoucherDate" }`. What I am saying is to replace it with what I have shown in my answer. In addition to specifying the `data` field you specify a `render` function.

Answer (score 0):

I am also working with MVC. You can format datetime in your c# methods.

Check this out : [C# DateTime to "YYYYMMDDHHMMSS" format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3025361/c-sharp-datetime-to-yyyymmddhhmmss-format).

By the way, take care of timezones offset :)