# Get the current month in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I've been programming in PHP for quite some time and now I'm trying to learn a new language. I'm creating a webpage and I want to display the current month automatically.
 In asp.net is the a way to do that? If there's a way can you guys help me?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# DateTime to "YYYYMMDDHHMMSS" format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3025361/c-sharp-datetime-to-yyyymmddhhmmss-format)

Answer (score 1):

`DateTime.Now.ToString("MMMM")` should do the job.

Here you have more info about date formats in .NET https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: Thanks :) just one more question how can I show the previous month? I mean, I'm creating a newsletter and it shows the articles of the previous month

Comment: @user2985255 sure DateTime.Today.AddMonths(-1).ToString("MMMM")

Answer (score 0):

If the date is 05/08/2017 and I need to get 04/08/2017 I use something like...

```
 DateTime d = DateTime.Now;
 d = d.AddMonths(-1);
```

this is get the date and subtract a month.

Answer (score -1):

Somehow someone -1d my question. The link that was provided only show how to display the date not how to subtract a month which is quite different!!!!