# How To Change Display Format Of System Current Date And Time In Asp.Net MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, datetime, datetime-format

Here I am trying to dispaly current system date and time in a format `August 19, 2017 6:58 PM` in Asp.net MVC view.
But instead of that I get `8/19/2017 7:07:29 PM`.How am I suppose to get the first format.
Below is my code:

```
<span class="description">
  Shared publicly -  @DateTime.Now              
</span>
```

Comment: Have a read of https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings and https://stackoverflow.com/a/24728080/34092

Comment: _@DateTime.Now.ToString("MMMM d, yyyy h:mm tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);_ please study [Custom Format Date and Time Format Strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want an explicit format, you can do this:

```
<span class="description">
  Shared publicly -  @DateTime.Now.ToString("MMMM d, yyyy h:mm tt")
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way

```
@{
    string formatted = @DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
}

<span class="description">
    Shared publicly -  @formatted              
</span>
```

[Here](http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-datetime/) is a good reference for different formats.