# How to get date in DateMonthYearHourMinuteSec in C# without slashes?

Tags: c#

I need to get date like this: 08242017175011
Without space or slashes. May I please know how to get date like above in C#?
Thanks

Comment: `DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyyyyHHmmss")`

Comment: Have you googled formatting dates using C#?

Comment: @Fabio. This should not be comment. Flesh it out into an answer. 

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# DateTime to "YYYYMMDDHHMMSS" format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3025361/c-sharp-datetime-to-yyyymmddhhmmss-format)

Comment: `DateTime.Now.ToString("MMddyyyyHHmmss")`

Comment: @AndrewTruckle - it very clearly a duplicated question - no need to repeat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
System.DateTime.Now.ToString("MMddyyyyHHmmss");
```