# What does +ffff stand for in this DateTime format ddd, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss +ffff

Tags: c#, datetime

I have run into some code where it does something like this:

```
SomeDateTimeObject.ToUniversalTime()
                                .ToString("ddd, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss +ffff", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
```

Now I am confused what +ffff stands for in this. Also, I would like to get the millisecond part of the datetime along with hours/minutes and seconds. what is the format for that?

Comment: `ffff` are ten thousandths of a second. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings. Milliseconds are `fff`.

Comment: So basically it's the millisecond part of the DateTime? e.g. 2009-06-15T13:45:30.6175000 will give 6175 (which is the milliseconds). is that correct?

Comment: The fs are fractions of a second. You can move it where you please in the format string. `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fff` will return 3 digits for the fractional seconds. When you start asking for more precision, the docs warn that the system clock may not actually deliver on that promise. _"The precision of date and time values depends on the resolution of the system clock"_

Comment: Alright, makes sense. So in order to get the milliseconds part of the date time I need to do something like HH:mm:ss.fff maybe. Thanks

Comment: **Note:** the actual useful answer in the **duplicate** mentioned above is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24728080/585968).  Thanks @Jasen

Comment: There are also two answers that link to the Microsoft documentation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"ff..." is used for fractions of a second

See [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings) for more details of custom date and time formatting.