# Change format of date in vb.net

Tags: mysql, vb.net, visual-studio-2017

I want to change the format of a date in vb.net so I can insert it in a MySQL table.

my code:

```
LblDateInc.Text = Date.Today
```

result: `10/18/2017`

in mysql table the column date need to look like this: `2017/10/18`

so how to change the format of the date in vb.net or in mysql
thank you

Comment: Is the database column a string or date type?

Comment: the database column a date type

Comment: Also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3025361/c-sharp-datetime-to-yyyymmddhhmmss-format)

Comment: Use `ToString("yourformatstring")`, it's in [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tostring?view=netframework-4.7.1#System_DateTime_ToString_System_String_).

Comment: @AFriend it work thank you :)

Comment: Possibel duplicate of [Convert Datetime Format in Vb.net](//stackoverflow.com/q/22397856) *(better dup target aimed at VB.Net, however, the syntax is not that different)*.

Comment: Sidenote: If you need a sortable and non-locale dependent (always a good idea) format, use a standard format, i.e. ISO8601 `2017-10-18`. Every reasonable date/string conversion function/class/whatever should support this.

Comment: *in mysql table the column date need to look like this: `2017/10/18`* Then you are doing it wrong.  Dates do not have a format; strings do.  Strings wont act like dates

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use this

```
LiblDateInc.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd")
```

Comment: You seriously don't need to answer this, it isn't the first time someone has asked how to format a date in .Net. - [Format date in C#](//stackoverflow.com/a/2151752)

Comment: Also `DateTime.Now` is not needed as the OP isn't interested in the time, so `DateTime.Today.ToString("yyy/MM/dd")` would work just as well.