# DateTime.TryParseExact returns false for some string in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, xamarin, xamarin.forms, c#-6.0

I am facing an issue in the parsing of the date. I have made following common function.

```
public static string ConvertedDate(string date)
        {
            if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(date))
            {
                DateTime returnValue;
                bool flag = DateTime.TryParseExact(date, "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out returnValue);
                return flag ? returnValue.ToString("MM.dd.yyyy") : null;
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
```

**But very strange thing happens some strings are successfully converted into DateTime but some return false.**

For example :

> "2017-05-11 12:00:24" this string parse successfully.
>
> "2015-03-06 20:18:42" this string can not.

The format of the string is same.

**I observed that when "hour(hh)" goes above 12 then it cannot be parsed.**

Comment: Your observation should tell you something...perhaps that is not the right format?

Comment: See format [format specifier documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to change yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss to yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss, which is hours in 24 hour time.  Note the change from hh to HH.

See here: [C# DateTime to "YYYYMMDDHHMMSS" format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3025361/c-sharp-datetime-to-yyyymmddhhmmss-format)