# Getting Bad Request Error in azure Table storage Insert operation

Tags: c#, azure, console-application, azure-storage

I am getting the following error when executing a console webjob in azure

```
Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Executor.Executor.ExecuteSync[T]
(RESTCommand`1 cmd, IRetryPolicy policy, OperationContext operationContext) in c:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\release_dotnet_master\Lib\ClassLibraryCommon\Core\Executor\Executor.cs:line 677
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Executor.Executor.ExecuteSync[T]
(RESTCommand`1 cmd, IRetryPolicy policy, OperationContext operationContext) in c:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\release_dotnet_master\Lib\ClassLibraryCommon\Core\Executor\Executor.cs:line 604
at 
Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.TableOperation.Execute(CloudTableClient client, CloudTable table, TableRequestOptions requestOptions, OperationContext operationContext) in c:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\release_dotnet_master\Lib\ClassLibraryCommon\Table\TableOperation.cs:line 44
at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.CloudTable.Execute(TableOperation operation, TableRequestOptions requestOptions, OperationContext operationContext) in c:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\release_dotnet_master\Lib\ClassLibraryCommon\Table\CloudTable.cs:line 52
at pAvg15MinInstantInputWebJob.Avg15MinInstantInputJob.AverageCalculator(DateTime runningDate) in F:\Projects\LogiProjects\ProcessEye\Source\Kent.ProcessEye\pAvg15MinInstantInputWebJob\Avg15MinInstantInputJob.cs:line 246
Request Information
RequestID:855533de-0002-0066-2819-7f27ee000000
RequestDate:Wed, 27 Dec 2017 13:51:21 GMT
StatusMessage:Bad Request
ErrorCode:InvalidInput
ErrorMessage:Bad Request - Error in query syntax.
RequestId:855533de-0002-0066-2819-7f27ee000000
Time:2017-12-27T13:51:22.1788418Z
```

But running this application in locally it is working successfully.

Here is my codes

```
string connectionString1 = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AzureWebJobsDashboard"].ConnectionString;
CloudStorageAccount account1 = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(connectionString1);
CloudTableClient client1 = account1.CreateCloudTableClient();
CloudTable table2 = client1.GetTableReference(pAvg15MinInstantInput);
var row = new pAvg15MinInstantInputEntity();
row.PartitionKey = targetPartitionKey;
row.RowKey = rowDate.ToString();
row.avg = entity.average;
row.count = entity.count;
row.date = rowDate;
row.inputid = entity.inputid;
row.max = entity.max;
row.min = entity.min;
try
{
 TableOperation insertOperation = TableOperation.InsertOrReplace(row);
 table2.Execute(insertOperation);
 }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    Errorlogger(runningDate, "else ----->" + ex.ToString());
    return false;
   }
```

And the Entity class is as follows

```
public class pAvg15MinInstantInputEntity : TableEntity
{
    public DateTime? date { get; set; }
    public string inputid { get; set; }
    public double? min { get; set; }
    public double? max { get; set; }
    public double? avg { get; set; }
    public long? count { get; set; }
}
```

**UPDATE**

The entity values are as follows

```
average - 244.1
count - 3
date - 2017-12-27 10:15:26
inputid - 36-i1
max-244.1
min - 244.0
```

and the entity class is as follows

```
public class ResultModel
{
    public string inputid { get; set; }
    //public long hour { get; set; }
    //public long minute { get; set; }
    public double max { get; set; }
    public double min { get; set; }
    public DateTime date { get; set; }
    public double average { get; set; }
    public long count { get; set; }
}
```

Any solution to resolve this?

Comment: "Error in query syntax". Your input must be different between local and server.

Comment: How that happen if i am using same resource in both local and server?

Comment: I suggest you debug it. Are you using VS 2017? If so get the latest update and [see this](https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/debug-in-azure/)

Comment: I am using VS2015. After debugging I found out that the error occuring in insertion. Fetching data from table is possible.

Comment: You might be able to still attach a debugger with VS 2015 but at least add some kind of logging which shows your inputs.

Comment: I have seen cases where such issues occur due to caps in the file name, try using all lower case, re-try and let us know.

Comment: What’s is the value of “rowDate” variable?

Comment: It is a DateTime variable like '2017-12-27 13:00:00.000'

Comment: Thanks. One more thing: Can you share the output of `rowDate.ToString()` i.e. value you're setting for `RowKey`?

Comment: Like 2017-12-27T19:00:00 in string format

Comment: Both of these value look OK. 400 error is usually caused by invalid value. Will it be possible for you to share values for all entity attributes? Please edit your question and include them.

Comment: I updated the question. Please check it..

Comment: What is the value of `targetPartitionKey`?

Comment: It is like "20171227-SL00023-i1"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As  Gaurav Mantri mentioned that 400 error usually caused by **invalid value**.  According to your supplied value, it seems that all of the value are correct **except** **Rowkey**. I also can reproduce it if I use the following code, **as it contains charater '/'.**

```
RowKey = DateTime.Now.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

In your case, you could change the RowKey value to **fix value such as "test"** to test it.  We also could get more info about table enitity from [Understanding the Table Service Data Model.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/understanding-the-table-service-data-model)

> The following characters **are not allowed** in values for the **PartitionKey and RowKey** properties:
>
> The forward slash (/) character
>
> The backslash () character
>
> The number sign (#) character
>
> The question mark (?) character
>
> Control characters from U+0000 to U+001F, including:
>
> The horizontal tab (\t) character
>
> The linefeed (\n) character
>
> The carriage return (\r) character
>
> Control characters from U+007F to U+009F

---

**Updated:**

> Any solution to resolve this?

You could format the **rowDate** with following code

```
row.RowKey = rowDate.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss")
```

or

```
row.RowKey = rowDate.AddMilliseconds(1).Ticks.ToString()
```

More info about how to format the datatime, please to another [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3025361/c-sharp-datetime-to-yyyymmddhhmmss-format)

Comment: Do you test with RowKey with the fix value "test"  ?

Comment: In your case just need to format the  rowDate time. example code. `row.RowKey = rowDate.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss")`. How to format datetime, you also could refer to this SO [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3025361/c-sharp-datetime-to-yyyymmddhhmmss-format). I will update the answer.

Comment: Hi updated the answer with the following code         row.RowKey = rowDate.AddMilliseconds(1).Ticks.ToString()  which working in my case