# Converting custom formatted dates

Tags: c#, datetime, format, customization

I was wondering if it is possible to convert custom formatted DateTimes to something more standardized.

I have two types of date-formats in string.

```
string Date1 = @"06.12.2015 18.00";
string Date2 = @"1944-09-29";
```

and I want to convert both to these kind of format:

```
yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ssZ
```

How do i do this?

I tried

```
DateTime testdate = DateTime.ParseExact(Date1, 
                                       "yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ssZ", 
                                        CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

but with no luck.

EDIT: Thsi question was flagged as possible duplicate to another entry in StackOverflow. The difference here is, as Vadim Yarovikov in the comments below put it, a two part question. 
"1) Parse value to date and 2) Convert date to desired format."

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# DateTime to "YYYYMMDDHHMMSS" format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3025361/c-sharp-datetime-to-yyyymmddhhmmss-format)

Comment: I wouldnt say this is the same question actually, in that example the problem is about formatting a Datetime.now. thsi is about converting and formatting a string to another type of date time format? Am i wrong here?@VadimYarovikov

Comment: so your question consists of two different parts: 1) Parse value to date and 2) Convert date to desired format.

Comment: Yes, sorry if i was a bit missleading. Thank you for the clarification though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can provide *two* formats in one `DateTime.ParseExact` call:

```
string[] tests = new string[] {
  @"06.12.2015 18.00", 
  @"1944-09-29" 
};

var result = tests
  .Select(item => DateTime.ParseExact(
     item,
     new string[] { "d.M.yyyy H.m", "yyyy-M-d" },
     CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
     DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal))
  .Select(date => date.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, result));
```

Outcome:

```
2015-12-06T18:00:00Z
1944-09-29T12:00:00Z
```

**Side Note**: I think that the actual target format should be `"yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ"` (please, notice `HH` instead of `hh`) otherwise it's *impossible to distinguish* `6:00AM` and `6:00PM (18:00)`

Comment: Ahh i think i will try this but i want the conversion result to be in format: yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ssZ. Still Thank you alot ! :D @DemitryBychenko