# Convert DateTime in c# using year month day and time

Tags: c#, datetime, datetime-format

I have the following xml file:

```
<Test>
    <Header>
       <Title>Test</Title>
       <Time>Wed Mar 21 14:37:04 2018</Time>
...
```

I can parse it and get the time:

```
public DateTime Time
{
    get { return _time; }
    private set { _time = value; }
}

foreach (XElement el in header.Elements()) {
    if (String.Compare(el.Name.ToString(), "Time", true) == 0) {
        string format = el.Value;
        _time = DateTime.ParseExact(format, "ddd MMM d H:m:s yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        Console.WriteLine(_time);
    }
}
```

With the above solution, I can get the time but in the following format :

```
3/21/2018 2:56:40 PM
```

How can I get it in this format?

```
2018-03-21 14:56:40
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you want the returned format as a string?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean. You're parsing to a `DateTime` value. That doesn't have a format - it's just a value. If you want a string representation of that value in a particular format, you should call `ToString` and specify the format.

Comment: [Duplicate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3025361/c-sharp-datetime-to-yyyymmddhhmmss-format?rq=1)

Comment: @JAD No as a DateTime

Comment: @JADI tried that it didn't work

Comment: @JAD if I add >> string dateT = time.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"); and then Console.WriteLine(dateT), I can see it in the log

Comment: @JADbut I need it as DateTime not String

Answer (score 2):

Specifying a format doesn't make sense for a DateTime object. They have the months, days, years, minutes etc split up in their properties. [See the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime(v=vs.110).aspx).

It doesn't make sense to ask for these to be in a certain order, unless you want to convert it to a string:

```
time.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
```

If you want to access certain parts of the datetime, you can use their properties directly:

```
time.Year;
time.Month;
```

etc.

Comment: @Anton what exactly are you *trying* to do though? As I said in my answer, as long as you are working with a `DateTime`  object, the format is irrelevant. Once you use `ToString(format)` to specify a format, it is a string, and you lose `DateTime`-functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Use `DateTime.ToString(string format)` to do that.

```
foreach (XElement el in header.Elements()) {
    if (String.Compare(el.Name.ToString(), "Time", true) == 0) {
        string format = el.Value;
        _time = DateTime.ParseExact(format, "ddd MMM d H:m:s yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        Console.WriteLine(_time.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"));
    }
}
```