# How to get datetime without am

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

```
DateTime.Now => 04.01.2019 06:20:51 AM
```

but I want it to be

```
04.01.2019 18:20:51.
```

I want to get date without am any to string format

```
var events = myEntity.Select(d => EntityFunctions.DiffHours(d.StartDate, DateTime.Now) <= 3 &&
      EntityFunctions.DiffHours(d.StartDate, DateTime.Now) >= 0).Select(d => new
      {
          d.Id,
          d.CalendarId,
          d.Title,
          d.StartDate,
          d.Calendar.Name
      }).ToList();
```

Comment: Have you taken a look at the custom format string options?:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings

Comment: In debug mode you see date time in system date format. In code you can reformat when you convert it to string. `string myStringDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd.MM.yyy HH:mm:ss")`

Comment: DateTime.Now.ToString("s") or DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy") or whatever else you can think of. Have a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings

Comment: I could not convert DateTime.Now.ToString("dd.MM.yyy HH:mm:ss") in this query

Comment: @user2814672: Why not?  Is it trying to convert that to a LINQ to Entities expression?  In that case you wouldn't do the conversion in the query itself, you're just querying data here.  You'd format the string when *displaying* the data.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# DateTime to "YYYYMMDDHHMMSS" format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3025361/c-sharp-datetime-to-yyyymmddhhmmss-format)

Comment: @David StartDate, DateTime.Now comes with am so query run falsely.Start date=>2019-01-04 7:25:00  DateTime.Now=>2019-01-04 6:25:00 .when I substract,the result is 0 but I have one record

Comment: @user2814672: Do you mean you want to pass a value *to* your query as a custom format string?  If that's the case then it's not really clear what you're trying to do.  `EntityFunctions.DiffHours()` expects `DateTime` (or `TimeSpan`) values, not strings.  If this is what you're trying to do then it's starting to sound like you're chasing the wrong problem based on an incorrect assumption somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

```
    var from = DateTime.Now.AddHours(-3);
    var to= DateTime.Now;
    var events = myEntity.Where(d => d.StartDate >= from && d.StartDate <= to) 
                         .Select(d => new
                             {
                                d.Id,
                                d.CalendarId,
                                d.Title,
                                d.StartDate,
                                d.Calendar.Name
                             }).ToList();
```

Comment: Start date is 2019-01-04 19:25:00.00 in database but I saw date 2019-01-04 7:25:00.00 in query.I thougt that startdate should be as database record

Comment: @user2814672 System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture help you

Comment: How to use in this query

Comment: when ı use System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture in linq query, linq don't allow