# yyyy-mm-dd date format when date and month are single digit

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have date value in `sql` table in `yyyy-mm-dd` format but for  single digit date and month format like,
`1989-1-3` how can I display it to `1989-01-03` in `asp.net labels`.

Comment: Is the date saved as a date or a string?

Comment: @Fabulous date is saved as `NVARCHAR(10)`

Comment: Ok, so the single digit months and days... do they have the leading 0 in the NVARCHAR(10) field?

Comment: Please refer to [C# DateTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3025361/c-sharp-datetime-to-yyyymmddhhmmss-format/50508087#50508087)

Comment: Consider the answers below to see if they don't address your specific problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.ToString()` function to convert DateTime in `yyyy-MM-dd`

```
    DateTime date = new DateTime(1989,01,03);
    string strDate = date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

You can assign value of `strDate` to `asp.net label`

I believe `dr["DOB"]` is of datatype `DateTime?` i.e. Nullable DateTime. If your `DateTime` is of Nullable then try with

```
lblDOB.Text = dr["DOB"].Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

POC: [.net Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/9RlP1S)

Comment: I am getting the value from DataTable `lblDOB.Text = dr["DOB"].ToString();`, here `lblDOB` is the label name.

Comment: You should try `lblDOB.Text = dr["DOB"].ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");`. Need to pass **"yyyy-MM-dd"** to `.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")` method

Comment: No getting error `No overload for method 'ToString' takes 1 arguments`

Comment: I guess your date time is nullable, kindly check my updated answer

Answer (score 1):

Try this assuming that you are importing the value `dr["DOB"].ToString();` from database as string.

```
#region date formatting 
string str = dr["DOB"].ToString();
//before first appearance of "-"
string result = str.Substring(0, str.IndexOf("-"));
//between two "-"
var middleDigit = str.Split('-')[1];
if (Convert.ToInt16(middleDigit) < 10)
{
    middleDigit = "0" + middleDigit;
}
//after last "-"
var last_ = str.Substring(str.LastIndexOf('-') + 1);
if (Convert.ToInt16(last_) < 10)
{
    last_ = "0" + last_;
}

lblDOB.Text = result + "-" + middleDigit.ToString() + "-" + last_.ToString();
#endregion
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always use `var dt = DateTime.Parse(string)` and after that format it as you want.
Example format: `dt.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ASP.NET Webforms, you can format the date as below:

```
<asp:Label ID="label_salary_sum" runat="server"
 Text='<%# Eval("Date", "{0:d MMM yyyy HH:mm}") %>'
/>
```

You can remove the Time in the format (HH:mm), if not required.

If you are assigning the value to Label from CodeBehind, then you can follow the below example:

```
label1.Text = date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

When using DataReader, below is the correct way to handle it. Hope your DOB Field is DB is of Type DateTime:

```
label1.Text = Convert.ToDateTime(dr["DOB"]).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

For a full reference of the Date Formatting, check the [link : Date Custom String Formats](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings)

Comment: I am getting the value from DataTable `lblDOB.Text = dr["DOB"].ToString();`, here `lblDOB` is the label name.

Comment: I tried the solution given by user4221591 and it worked. But I am not sure whether that solution is fully correct or not. Please can you help!!!

Comment: @nischalinn The solution of user4221591, if it works is well and good. but its a bit of code and string manipulation. Try my solution as well which is cleaner and more comprehensible.