# DateTimeOffSet usage for current date

Tags: c#

I have date field in database with 'datetimeoffset(7)'. It looks like

`2021-09-30 02:00:31.3000000 +00:00.`

As I understand it uses this structure:

`YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss[.nnnnnnn] [{+|-}hh:mm]`

I've tried this but "Now" is underlined :

```
var currentDate = DateTimeOffset.Now("YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss[.nnnnnnn] [{+|-}hh:mm]");
```

How can I get current date with this date structure?

Comment: Check example on [MSDN page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetimeoffset?view=net-5.0) . `DateTimeOffset.Now` is a property that will return a value of current date-time value in UTC. If you want to format to a string, you should try to use `DateTimeOffset.Now.ToString()`

Comment: DateTimeOffset.Now or DateTimeOffset.Now.ToString() gives me this date 9/30/2021 3:13:35 PM +03:00 but it's not correct structure I need.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C# DateTime to "YYYYMMDDHHMMSS" format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3025361/c-sharp-datetime-to-yyyymmddhhmmss-format)

Comment: Look at that "duplicate" to 2nd answer  ( https://stackoverflow.com/a/3025389/7167572 ), it shows exactly how to format datetime to the format you want.

Answer (score 1):

I belive this is format what you need:

```
var currentDate = DateTimeOffset.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.fffffff zzz");
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/63242998/8825020