# DateTime formatting option

Tags: c#, datetime, formatting

What is the appropriate DateTime formatting option in NET/C# to achieve more efficiently the same as this:

```
DateTimeOffset dt = <some_date_with_time>;
string dtStr = $"'{dt.Year}/{dt.Month}/{dt.Day} {dt.Hour}:{dt.Minute}:{dt.Second}'";
```

Comment: Do you want it exactly like this or shall the format be culture-dependent?

Comment: Please make an effort to search this site before posting a new quesstion. In this case, a search for `c# format datetime` found literally [hundreds of results] (https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%23%5D+format+datetime)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C# DateTime to "YYYYMMDDHHMMSS" format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3025361/c-sharp-datetime-to-yyyymmddhhmmss-format)

Comment: Exactly like that regardless the culture.

Comment: I think yes, as "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss" seems to be the correct option. I am just not sure if it is the correct, and if it will return the same for all cultures.

Answer (score 0):

DateTime.ToString method is what you looking for. For example:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
string timeStr = dt.ToString(); //it will return full datetime like 06/18/2022 08:07PM
```

Check [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tostring?view=net-6.0) for more formatting options.

Comment: Thanks for your response. But what is the right option to return always 2008-10-31 17:04:32 and regardless the culture?

Answer (score 0):

```
string dtStr = dt.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss")
```

Answering your comment, this is what you need:

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime(2008, 10, 31, 17, 4, 32);
string timeStr = dt.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
```