# How to get a datetime format like "00:00:00"?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, time, swagger

my entity like that

```
public string CompanyName { get; set; }
public bool IsVerified  { get; set; } = false;
public DateTime permissionStartDate { get; set; }
public DateTime permissionEndDate { get; set; }
```

my swagger like that

```
{
  "id": 0,
  "companyName": "string",
  "isVerified": true,
  "permissionStartDate": "2023-01-05T13:53:38.409Z",
  "permissionEndDate": "2023-01-05T13:53:38.409Z"
}
```

How can I send data from json in 00:00:00 format.

Comment: You only want the time portion without the date?

Comment: You shouldn't really send data in HH:MM:SS format that's why It's converted to [ISO 8601](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format. DateTime calls internally ToString which converts it to that format.
If you only want the time portion then use `permissionStartDate.ToString("HH:mm:ss")` when converting to JSON

Comment: You could try `TimeOnly` struct, but I think that it doesn't have a default json converter and you would have to write one yourself

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C# DateTime to "YYYYMMDDHHMMSS" format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3025361/c-sharp-datetime-to-yyyymmddhhmmss-format)

Comment: If its just time what should happen when its deserialized into your entity again where its a DateTime?

Comment: @theemee yes i want it this way.

Comment: @Chiwen are you using `System.Text.Json` or `Newtonsoft.Json`?

Comment: @Chiwen your issue get sorted?

Comment: @SachithWickramaarachchi yes it is solved thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write some custom class to modify your response by Overriding [JsonConverter](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm) by [newtonsoft](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/).

So, your custom class should be something like this,

```
public class CustomTimeConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(DateTime);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var date = (DateTime)value;
        writer.WriteValue(date.ToString("HH:mm:ss"));
    }
}
```

here you don't need to implement the `ReadJson()`, because it's used to deserialize JSON data into an object and `CustomTimeConverter` is only used to serialize `DateTime` objects to JSON.

Your response class should be like this,

```
public class ResponseClass
{
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    public bool IsVerified { get; set; } = false;

    [JsonConverter(typeof(CustomTimeConverter))]
    public DateTime permissionStartDate { get; set; }

    [JsonConverter(typeof(CustomTimeConverter))]
    public DateTime permissionEndDate { get; set; }
}
```

This is a sample code snippet to test the above implementation.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var entity = new ResponseClass
    {
        CompanyName = "stackoverflow",
        IsVerified = true,
        permissionStartDate = new DateTime(2023, 1, 5, 12, 0, 0),
        permissionEndDate = new DateTime(2023, 1, 5, 15, 0, 0)
    };

    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(entity , Formatting.Indented);
    Console.WriteLine(json);
}
```

and output is:

```
{
  "CompanyName": "stackoverflow",
  "IsVerified": true,
  "permissionStartDate": "12:00:00",
  "permissionEndDate": "15:00:00"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution would be to write a custom `JsonConverter`

If you are using `System.Text.Json`:

```cs
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Text.Json;
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;

public class TimeConverter : JsonConverter<DateTime> {
    public override DateTime Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options) {
        return reader.GetDateTime();
    }

    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, DateTime value, JsonSerializerOptions options) {
        writer.WriteStringValue(value.ToString("HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
    }
}

public class Entity {
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    public bool IsVerified  { get; set; } = false;
    [JsonConverter(typeof(TimeConverter))]
    public DateTime permissionStartDate { get; set; }
    [JsonConverter(typeof(TimeConverter))]
    public DateTime permissionEndDate { get; set; }
}
```